# iOS: iCarousel delegate method not called when first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, icarousel

I've implemented iCarousel and the following delegate.

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel
```

This delegate calls properly when I  scroll, but doesn't get call when I first load the carousel at index 0. This is because by default Icarosuel default index is 0.

The only work around I have is calling the delegate method when the index is 0 like so.

```
  if (index == 0) {
        [self carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:self.carousel];
    }
```

I need the delegate method called because this is where I change quite a few things that isn't part of the carousel view. So I can use any of the data sources at all.

Comment: Not sure the carousel library being used, but one idea is to simply call the delegate yourself once it's initialized.

Comment: Isolate these "few things" into a separate method and call it before you first load a carousel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41976632/5461400

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var objCarosel: iCarousel!

override func viewDidLoad()
{    
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //Set delegate and datasource help to call predefine methods.   
   objCarosel.delegate = self      
   objCarosel.dataSource = self    
   objCarosel.reloadData()    
}
```